# Correct procedure to identify a component and obtain the datasheet

Tags: identification, components, repair

I'm not sure what should be the correct procedure to obtain a component's datasheet starting from the component's package code.

I searched in the other questions, but I found mostly people asking what is a certain component, while I'd be interested in knowing the general procedure to follow to identify an unknown component.

In some cases, for complex components as ICs, a google search of the code shown on the package is sufficient to obtain the relevant datasheet, but I had less success with components as transistors, mosfets and so on.

[image: An example component]

An example: this component is identified as Q1 in the board, leading to think it is a mosfet. BTW, the terminals are identified as "B, C, E", as it was a transistor, and not "G, S, D" as I was expecting.
In this case I would try some google searches with the following strings:

- GS H 2053 F 01 datasheet
- 2053 Transistor datasheet
- 2053 Mosfet datasheet

but none of them would show relevant results.
Is there any coding convention for this kind of component that can be useful to know for a better search?

Comment: Just a note on some of your terminology - a MOFSE**T** is a **T**ranistor. A device which is a transistor, but not a MOSFET, is (probably) a BJT (although there other options).

Comment: BCE is for BJTs. GSD is MOSFETs,

Comment: Thank you @DKNguyen: as you can see, my inexperience lead me to think that a three pin non-transistor power component in a psu should have been a Mosfet.
Brhans 's note is clarifying, although I'm not sure a Mosfet's datasheet contains the word Transistor alone, most probably the entire acronym.

Comment: @penguin86 um, most datasheets I came across do in fact contain the word transistor if they are transistor datasheets.